# What is the best way to create a deep copy of state inside immer producer

Tags: reactjs, redux, deep-copy, immer.js

I have a wizard based GUI where I need to create a copy of some original state in my redux store and save it to a new property called `stageEdits` that can be used as a temporary place to make changes which can then be saved back to the original state, or discarded...

My first attempt was to use immer and nested produce functions like so:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draftState) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionName.EditStage:
        const stage = findStageById(draftState, action.stageId);
        draftState.stageEdits = produce(stage, (draftStage) => {
          draftStage.isEditing = true;
        }
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

however, this resulted in `TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked` which appears to be an issue when trying to use nested producer functions... so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this...

Should I be using something like loDash `cloneDeep`, or is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**
This question is specifically about how to create a deepCopy of state inside the Immer produce function... right now, when I try to use `cloneDeep` against the draftState proxy object returned by Immer, anything that is an array is returned as a number instead of a copy of the array itself...

based on the link provided by @azundo, I ended up cloning the originalState instead of the draftState... this fixed my problem... see the revised code below for example:

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

const reducer = (currentState, action) => {
  return produce(currentState, (draftState) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionName.EditStage:
        const stage = findStageById(currentState, action.stageId);
        draftState.stageEdits = cloneDeep(stage);
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Pick `clone` over `lodash`, it's 2kb whilst `lodash` is 70kb

Comment: @Aleks if you import like `lodash/clone` it will be 2kb too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you checked out the `original` function from `immer`? That might be what you want to wrap `stage` in before passing it to your nested producer. That requires that you haven't edited `stage` in the outer producer since you're getting the original non-proxied stage without any edits. https://github.com/immerjs/immer#extracting-the-original-object-from-a-proxied-instance

Comment: Thanks @azundo... that link helped lead me to the eventual answer... rather than cloning the draftState, I needed to clone the currentState instead... that fixed my problem...